# How to write cucumber acceptance for Java Library

Tags: cucumber-java

I am in newbie in Cucumber and want to write acceptance test using it.
Important thing here is, I am developing library here so I don't have any http endpoint or any interface.
This library has java methods and further these methods will be consumed by client.
I want to write acceptance for library first.
Following is service which will be consumed by client and want to write ac for this.

How can I do that?

```
public class HelloWorld{
   public String helloWorld(){
      return "Hello World";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that Cucumber is a good tool for writing tests like that because Cucumber is a sort of a tool that integrates less technical people and more technical people. Better to use pure Java for your need.

However if you want to have some theory you can start from writing a gherkin script:

```
Feature: Lib testing

  Scenario: Test HelloWorld
    Given an object of click.webelement.cucumber.lib.HelloWorld class
    And calling helloWorld method
    Then method returns: Hello World
```

Then you need to have step definition:

```java
public class StepDefs {

    @Inject
    ObjMethContainer container;

    @Given("an object of {} class")
    public void given(String clazz) throws Exception {
        container.o = Class
                .forName(clazz)
                .getConstructor()
                .newInstance(new Object[]{});
    }

    @When("calling {} method")
    public void when(String method) throws Exception {
        container.m = container.o.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(method);
    }

    @Then("method returns: {}")
    public void then(String val) throws Exception {
        assert val.equals(container.m.invoke(container.o));
    }

}
```

**N.B.** - To share state between steps you need to apply some DI (in my example I use Guice). Where `ObjMethContainer` is simply:

```java
@ScenarioScoped
public class ObjMethContainer {

    public Object o;
    public Method m;

}
```

In my example I generalized exceptions to `Exception` to save space.

Comment: I think it looks fine but looking groovy version for this. Can you suggest something on groovy as well.